# Execute two ajax posts in one click and show content in two different places

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a shopping cart from which I can remove products, and a cartpage with all products on it. I can remove products from both seperately using ajax, but

I would like if you click remove in one of the two places, that they are removed and the content is reloaded in both places. Now only 1 place is reloaded, and I can only see changes in the other place when I refresh my page.

How can this be done?

My code currently:

```
// Verwijder een product uit de winkelmand
tpj('.topnav--cart').on('click', '.remove', function(event) {
  // Stop de anchor tag van zijn normale gedrag
  event.preventDefault();
  // Haal het id op (de productnaam in dit geval)
  var $remove = tpj(this).attr('id');
  url = 'includes/shoppingcart.php';
  // Post bovenstaande waardes naar de action van de form
  var posting = tpj.post( url, { remove: $remove} );
  // Stop het resultaat in een div met het id #result
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = tpj( data );
    tpj( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
  });
});


// Verwijder een product uit het winkelmandoverzicht
tpj('.cartpage').on('click', '.remove', function(event) {
  // Stop de anchor tag van zijn normale gedrag
  event.preventDefault();
  // Haal het id op (de productnaam in dit geval)
  var $remove = tpj(this).attr('id');
  url = 'includes/cartoverzicht.php';
  // Post bovenstaande waardes naar de action van de form
  var posting = tpj.post( url, { remove: $remove} );
  // Stop het resultaat in een div met het id #result
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = tpj( data );
    tpj( "#cartresult" ).empty().append( content );
  });
});
```

So there are currently two ajax scripts and two php scripts, is it possible that when I click one of the two triggers, that both are fired?

Comment: why on earth have you got two PHP scripts to do the same action?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really to that, because if one request fails, another one might execute. But if you REALLY want to execute two requests at once, you should do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/creativecouple/sPkXh/).

```
var one = function(ajax_request)

var two = function(ajax_request)

$.when(one, two).then(function(){
        $('.result').text(data)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you could simply create 2 functions that both execute on either element click :

```
var post1 = function($remove) {
    url = 'includes/shoppingcart.php';
    var posting = tpj.post( url, { remove: $remove} );
    posting.done(function( data ) {
      var content = tpj( data );
      tpj( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
    });
}

var post2 = function($remove) {
  url = 'includes/cartoverzicht.php';
  var posting = tpj.post( url, { remove: $remove} );
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = tpj( data );
    tpj( "#cartresult" ).empty().append( content );
  });
} 

tpj('.topnav--cart').on('click', '.remove', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $remove = tpj(this).attr('id');
  post1($remove);
  post2($remove);
}

tpj('.cartpage').on('click', '.remove', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $remove = tpj(this).attr('id');
  post1($remove);
  post2($remove);
}
```

But the best idea would maybe be to create a special route that executes your 2 actions at once and call this script on your 2 buttons :

```
var removeItem = function($remove) {
  url = 'includes/removeItem.php';
  var posting = tpj.post( url, { remove: $remove} );
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = tpj( data );
    tpj( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
    tpj( "#cartresult" ).empty().append( content );
  });
}

tpj('.topnav--cart').on('click', '.remove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $remove = tpj(this).attr('id');
    removeItem($remove);
}

tpj('.cartpage').on('click', '.remove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $remove = tpj(this).attr('id');
    removeItem($remove);
}
```